# Texture is rendered as scaled and repeating along X axis

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to render a framebuffer as a texture on a triangle strip with OpenGL. It renders the buffer to the triangle strip fine, but the texture itself doesn't fill the entire triangle strip. It also repeats horizontally, which I can't figure out.

If I don't supply what you need in this question, please just ask, and don't assume that I should have zipped my entire project. I would if I could, but it's proprietary, and I would get in trouble.

Here's what the OpenGL window looks like when I run it. The code is meant to draw a rectangle through the middle of the screen vertically, in the center of the screen (horizontally).

[image]

The rectangles are meant to be white, so don't worry about that.

drawFrame():
[image]

initScene() and initTexture():
[image]

The texture data itself is fine, that I am sure of. It's just a buffer that I draw on with some of my own functions.

Triangle strip and texture coords:
[image]

If you need anything else, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to add that when I draw the rectangle horizontally, the first repetition has a higher y coordinate than the other repetitions. http://i.imgur.com/2W2qqD8.png

Comment: 1. You can edit your post. 2. You should use the StackOverflow way of typing code - your pictures are hard to read and hard to edit - what if someone asks for more code in a certain section?

Comment: I did images so it couldn't be indexed by search engines. Any help? Turns out there's only one repeated texture, and it's just being stretched... or something. I filled all of the buffer but some of the right edge and got this: http://i.imgur.com/WEw1XXn.png

Comment: Indexed by search engines? I can't imagine why, you have nothing original in your code. Besides, obscurity is the worst form of security. You've just made it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Use an FBO instead of doing client memory pixel transfer, and draw into a texture attachment. It is possible that you are using a PBO (you have not shown enough code), so `glTexSubImage2D (...)` might be less expensive, but by far the easier way to draw to a framebuffer and use it as a texture is to use an FBO.

Comment: I seriously doubt this causes the problem, but don't you want GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR in your MIN_FILTER?

Comment: Or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`... GL is a silly API, they never came up with a proper way to set the filter for the mipmap they just tacked it onto the minification filter at the last minute :P It is not invalid to use a texture image with a mipmap chain without a mip filter though.